# What is the difference between using { } and ( ) for return statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am learning ReactJS and I wanted to know the difference in using curly braces and parenthesis for return statements.
Here is a block of code

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            count: 0
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                count: prevState.count + 1
            }
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
                <br />
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change!</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App
```

In the `handleClick` function, `return` has curly braces and in the `render` function, it has parenthesis.
Interchanging them in either case gives me an Error.
So...I just wanted to know if there is any difference and which one is to be used when

Comment: a curly bracket would generally denote an object that is being returned, the parenthesis here aren't needed as it is being used as a grouping operator to group the jsx being returned. remember this gets transpiled from jsx to `return React.createElement('div', ...)`

Comment: The meaning of `()` is listed under "Grouping Operator' on the first duplicate.

Comment: @JohnRuddell - It's common practice in React-world because otherwise people have a tendency to put a newline after `return` and start the JSX on the next line...which ends up returning `undefined`, since ASI inserts a `;` after the `return`. :-( Personally, I prefer `return <div>` but that seems not to be popular for some reason.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yep, i prefer that as well. good information for the question though :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell - Glad I'm not the only one!